# Showing that derivative of conjugate is conjugate of derivative, using chain rule

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that the derivative of the conjugate is the conjugate of the derivative, i.e.
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}[f(x)^*]}{\mathrm{d}x} = \biggl[\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\biggr]^*,
$$
using the chain rule.

Calling the conjugate * function '\operatorname{conj}', we have by chain rule
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{conj}(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \dfrac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{conj}(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}[f(x)]} \cdot \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$

Now,
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{conj}(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}[f(x)]}
\equiv \lim \limits_{h \to 0}{\frac{\operatorname{conj}(f(x)+h)-\operatorname{conj}(f(x))}{h}}
= \lim \limits_{h \to 0}{\frac{h^*}{h}}
$$

where $h \in C$.

I wasn't sure how to evaluate that limit, but according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+z*%2Fz%2C+z+goes+to+0), it is = 1.

But that doesn't make sense, since then
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{conj}(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}x}
= 1 \cdot \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x},
$$
when it should be $\biggl[\dfrac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\biggr]^*$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Conjugation is not complex differentiable. You need to look at real differentiability and the partial derivatives.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Can you please elaborate? Are you saying the "derivative of conjugate is conjugate of derivative" rule doesn't always hold?

Comment: Are you talking about the complex conjugate $z\to z^*$? It isn't differentiable as a complex function of $z$. Consider it as a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$; that is, consider the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)^*$ as a function of the real and imaginary parts of $z$.

Comment: It holds if by derivative you mean the derivative of the function viewed as a function of (one or) two real variables. If by derivative you mean complex derivative, then if $f(z)$ is complex differentiable on $U$, it's conjugate isn't (unless $f$ is constant).

Comment: @DanielFischer : I meant it in the first sense (should have specified that x is real in f(x)). Nonetheless, the value of f(x) could still be complex. Why does using the chain rule as I did in my example seem to give me the wrong result?

Comment: Then it is true, but you need to view conjugation as a function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and use the partial derivatives/the Jacobi matrix. [Or use the fact that conjugation is real-linear, and that linear maps are their own derivative plus the chain rule.]

Comment: Your post would benefit from better formatting of formulas. See [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 23):

So, $f$ is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$ (which should have been made clear from the beginning). Suppose $f$ is differentiable at a point $x$, and $f'(x)=a$. This means exactly that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-ah|}{h} = 0 \tag1$$
Recalling that $|z|=|\bar z|$ for every complex number, we conclude from (1) that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left|\overline{f(x+h)}-\overline{f(x)}-\bar a h\right|}{h} = 0 \tag2$$
(No need for bar over $h$, since $h$ is real.) Equation (2) says precisely that $\bar f$ has derivative $\bar a$ at $x$.

---

Generally, approaching derivatives via (1) rather than 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=a$$
is a good practice that will pay off in multivariable calculus.

Comment: Can we take h to the RHS and finally write lim(h->0) f(x+h) - f(x) - ah =0 ?

Comment: @fahd .... Yes, I think so, though you have to be careful with limits. In this case, since $h$ does in fact go to zero, then the numerator must go to zero as well (indeed, go to zero faster than $h$ does) in order for the limit to go to zero.