# Is the complex conjugate of a solution of a differential equation is a solution too?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

That might be a naive question here, though I can't simply see the answer that follows.I have a differential equation where its operators are real, It's written that if it has a solution, where it can be a complex function, then it's complex conjugate is a solution too. How is that?

---

p.s. For the sake of mathematical "proof reading", this is generally not true but true for real, linear differential equations as specified in the answer.

Comment: Conjugation and differentiation commute in this case.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks I also after reading your comment referred to this(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878258/showing-that-derivative-of-conjugate-is-conjugate-of-derivative-using-chain-rul)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ is a differentiable function. Then, $f$ is differentiable if and only if $\overline{f}$ is differentiable, and in this case, $\frac{d\overline{f}}{dx} = \overline{\left(\frac{df}{dx}\right)}$; i.e taking derivatives commutes with taking complex conjugation. Now, let $D$ be a real, linear differential operator, for example, like $D = \sum_{k=1}^n \phi_k \frac{d^k}{dx^k}$, where $\phi_k: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$. Then, $D\left(\overline{f}\right) = \overline{D(f)}$. So, one is zero if and only if the other is zero, which means $f$ is a solution if and only if $\overline{f}$ is a solution.