# What is the derivative of square modulus of a complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am reading an article that contains a function $f(z) = |z|^2$, $z$ is a complex number.

The authors calculated the derivative of the function $f(z)$ with respects to $z$:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} f(z)}{\mathrm{d} z} = \overline{-2z}$

I do not understand why authors end up with this result.

Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to differentiate $f(z)=z\overline{z}$. Use product rule and the fact that [derivative of conjugate is conjugate of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/878258/955582)

Comment: Conjugation is not complex differentiable

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Might the authors of the paper be treating $z$ and $\bar{z}$ as independent complex variables? (This is sometimes more convenient than using $x$ and $y$ with $z = x+iy$ and $\bar{z} = x - iy$.)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks, I realize little knowledge is bad....